# Rearranging columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The current codes I am working on requires me to rearrange the columns in VBA. It has to arranged according to the header, and the headers are **"V-d(1)", "V-g(1)", "I-d(1)", "I-g(1)"**, and this set repeats for numbers 2, 3, etc etc. (e.g **V-d(2), I-g(4)**). These data are usually jumbled up and I have to arrange them in ascending numbers.

It does not matter if V-g, V-d, I-d or I-g comes first.

```
Dim num, numadj As Integer
Dim colu, coladj
Range("A1").Select
Do While Range("A1").Offset(0, i - 1).Value <> ""
    colu = ActiveCell.Value
    coladj = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    num = Left(Right(colu.Text, 2), 1)
    numadj = Left(Right(coladj.Text, 2), 1)
    If num > numadj Then
        colu.EntireColumn.Cut Destination:=Columns("Z:Z")
        coladj.EntireColumn.Cut Destination:=colu
        Columns("Z:Z").Select.Cut Destination:=coladj
        i = i + 1
    Else
    i = i + 1
    End If
Loop
```

I am very new to VBA so please forgive me for any dumb codes that I have created!!! Thank you in advance everyone!

Comment: How far do numbers extend? Hundreds? Thousands?

Comment: @parfait At most 10!

Comment: Do you use Excel for Windows?

Comment: @parfait yes I do!

Comment: you can sort by column headers from left to right https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/897-excel-sort-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider an SQL and RegEx solution to select columns in a specified arrangement. SQL works in Excel for PC which can access Windows' Jet/ACE SQL Engine to query its own workbook like a database table.

Due to the variable nature of sets ranging 3-10, consider finding the highest number set by extracting the numbers from column headers with RegEx using the defined function, `FindHighestNumberSet`. Then have `RunSQL` subroutine call the function to build SQL string dynamically.

Below assumes you have data currently in a tab named *DATA* with an empty tab named *RESULTS* which will output query results. Two ADO connection strings are available.

**Function** *(iterating across column headers to extract highest number)*

```
Function FindHighestNumberSet() As Integer
    Dim lastcol As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim num As Integer: num = 0
    Dim regEx As Object

    ' CONFIGURE REGEX OBJECT
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
       .Global = True
       .MultiLine = True
       .IgnoreCase = False
       .Pattern = "[^0-9]"
    End With

    With Worksheets("DATA")
       lastcol = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

       For i = 1 To lastcol
         ' EXTRACT NUMBERS FROM COLUMN HEADERS
         num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(num, CInt(regEx.Replace(.Cells(1, i), "")))
       Next i

    End With

    FindHighestNumberSet = num
End Function
```

**Macro** *(main module looping through result of above function)*

```
Sub RunSQL()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    ' DRIVER AND PROVIDER CONNECTION STRINGS
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=" & Activeworkbook.FullName & ";"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & "';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    ' FIRST THREE SETS
    strSQL = " SELECT t.[V-d(1)], t.[I-d(1)], t.[I-g(1)]," _
                  & " t.[V-d(2)], t.[I-d(2)], t.[I-g(2)]," _
                  & " t.[V-d(3)], t.[I-d(3)], t.[I-g(3)]"

    ' VARIABLE 4+ SETS
    For i = 4 To FindHighestNumberSet
        strSQL = strSQL & ", t.[V-d(" & i & ")], t.[I-d(" & i & ")], t.[I-g(" & i & ")]"
    Next i

    ' FROM CLAUSE
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [DATA$] t"

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' COLUMN HEADERS
    For i = 1 To rst.Fields.Count
        Worksheets("RESULTS").Cells(1, i) = rst.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next i

    ' DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("RESULTS").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close: conn.Close
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing

    MsgBox "Successfully ran SQL query!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Set rst = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
    MsgBox Err.Number & " = " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your work! What if it does not always have 10 sets?  The system generates 3-10 sets, it is not fixed always. Does the code still work?

Comment: As mentioned, adjust the query's columns. Specifically, remove the items in `SELECT` clause. Do you know in advance the set number?

Comment: @parfair Nope, I will not know in advance! The set number is generated by another system and then this code will run

Comment: See update with SQL being dynamically built from finding highest number in column header (extracted using RegEx). And congrats as you just learned of two special purpose languages: SQL and RegEx! May seem overkill but you avoid cutting and pasting columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort vertically by a helper row with something like this (tested):

```
Sub test() ': Cells.Delete: [b2:d8] = Split("V-d(10) V-d(2) V-d(1)") ' used for testing
    Dim r As Range: Set r = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange  ' specify the range to be sorted here

    r.Rows(2).Insert xlShiftDown ' insert helper row to sort by. (used 2nd row instead 1st so that it is auto included in the range)
    r.Rows(2).FormulaR1C1 = "=-RIGHT(R[-1]C,LEN(R[-1]C)-3)" ' to get the numbers from the column header cells above, so adjust if needed

    r.Sort r.Rows(2) ' sort vertically by the helper row
    r.Rows(2).Delete xlShiftUp ' delete the temp row
End Sub
```